# In Beautiful Soup, how do I dynamically search through a table to find a specific element?

Tags: python, html, search, youtube, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a program that takes a youtube playlist url and extracts the links for each of the videos in the playlist.  I've hardcoded a playlist for simplicity.  Here's what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_to_scrape = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYlZ5VtcfgiuJpQve20C9WHQaIHrCdykv'

hostname = 'http://www.youtube.com'

r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

video_links = []

for tr in soup.select(".pl-video-list tr"):
    td = tr.findAll('td')

    if len(td) > 0:
        relative_link = td[3].find('a')['href'] #eww, gross
        video_links.append(hostname + relative_link);

print video_links
```

As it stands, this works for me.  However, I really don't like using a hardcoded index `3` to extract the url from the `<td>` element in the videos table.

How can I make this dynamic so that the index of the video url for each video can be found, rather than just assuming it's always going to be in position 3?

Comment: My prototyping mind tells me "Hey, as long as it works, why change it?". My API mind tells me "Why the heck is he not using the Youtube API for this?". Seriously, Youtube changes all. the. time. Even if you had a nicer way to check for where the link is, changes are it would be broken soon.

Comment: @FlavianHautbois because this is my first real python program D:

Comment: I advise you to have a look at the `google-api-python-client` and https://developers.google.com/youtube/ if you want to do more complicated stuff with Youtube's data ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could skip the table and go directly to the links:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'pl-video-title-link'}):
    video_links.append(hostname + a['href'])
```